# angularjs how to set text inside element based on textbox input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

My code is:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3">
            <checked-input ng-scope="$eventID"></checked-input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3">
            <output ng-scope="$postbackOutput">***This is where I want the text typed in the textbox to go***</output>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <a ng-click="generateURL($eventID)" class="btn-plus">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

So what I'm trying to do is get that `$eventID` that's inside the first column div, then pass it as an argument to the function call `generateURL()` when the link in the `<a>` tag is clicked in the third column. Inside the controller I have:

```
app.controller('postbackCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.generateURL = function(eventID) {
        $scope.postbackOutput = eventID;
    } 
});
```

But it doesn't seem to be setting the text in the `<output>` correctly. Could anyone help? I've just started out with angular so it's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just bind the var to the view with handlebar brackets:

```
<output ng-scope="$postbackOutput">
    {{ postbackOutput }}
</output>
```

[Here is a working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vfrhuTNVCuddEzEMPN0G)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried it and it doesn't seem to be working either :(

Comment: I added a simple plunkr to show it working, I think it is what you are trying to accomplish. Also I just looked up the ng-scope directive and wonder if that might be messing with things